# Java not able to read Firefox's certificate store (working fine with IE)

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate

My application is creating an Applet which is using the [OpenSC API](http://www.opensc-project.org/openct) to interact with an Aladdin eToken Pro smart card, and getting certificates from it.

The eToken card, at client, places the certificate in browsers certificate store. On server side client authentication is set too true. So server is requesting for client identification (client certificate).

I am able to access eToken using the applet in Internet Explorer, but in case of Firefox it prompts me to select the certificate identification. But in the selection area everything is blank.

The Popup message is `"Request authentication. Please select certificate to be used for authentication"` and selection area is blank.

A search on internet resulted in me discovering that I have to do `jss configuration` on Firefox adding (`jss.dll and jss.jar`), I have done this but the issue remains unresolved. I think the issue is java is not able to read firefox certificate store but it can read IE's certificate store.

Can anybody suggest me how to go about solving this problem?